# hide label for marker points in mscharts

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mschart

In mscharts i m able to give label to the marker points using the function 
**databindcrosstable** using the code

```
Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dr, "something", "anything", "a_data", "label=c_score")
```

now i want to hide the c_score label for the marker points.

I m showing the label in the tooltip on mouse hover using the code

```
e.Text = result.Series.Points(result.PointIndex).YValues(0) & vbCr & result.Series.Points(result.PointIndex).Label
```

I was trying this code in customize event which still shows the marker labels

```
Private Sub Chart1_Customize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Chart1.Customize
    For Each ser As Series In Chart1.Series
        For Each dp As DataPoint In ser.Points
            dp.IsValueShownAsLabel = False
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

if there is anything as dp.labelvisible = false

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your problem, can't you not remove the `label=c_score` on the binding, also i thing its `IsValueShownAsLabel=false`. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

on the form load i m using the databindcrosstable.

In the form load i have added

```
For Each ser As Series In Chart1.Series
                    For Each dp As DataPoint In ser.Points
            dp.Tag = dp.Label
            dp.Label = ""
        Next
Next
```

and on the chart1 tooltiptext event i have done: -

```
Private Sub Chart1_GetToolTipText(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ToolTipEventArgs) Handles Chart1.GetToolTipText
    Dim result As HitTestResult
    Select Case e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType
        Case ChartElementType.DataPoint
            result = e.HitTestResult
            e.Text = "Overall Quality: " & result.Series.Points(result.PointIndex).YValues(0) & " " & result.Series.Points(result.PointIndex).Tag
    End Select
End Sub
```